# FTP and permissions

Tags: permissions, tftp

I am having trouble with file permissions. There are tons of websites and other sources regarding this. But none are addressing my issue.
When I set a permission on a folder I have with

```
chmod 660 [name of folder]
```

The system will restrict outside PCs from having access to the folder. But, if I use

```
chmod 770 [name of folder]
```

I can gain access to the folder, download it and delete data from it. Is there something I do not get? I thought that with a "0" in the last digit of the three numbers that it will not let other users or groups alter and gain access to folder. What am I not understanding?

Comment: Is the user you're logging into with FTP the **owner** of the file, or in the same group as the file owner?

Comment: I am assuming logging in as the other. When I initiate FTP I enter IP address, username, and password. If I am understanding how this operates correctly, if I FTP into my pi, it is considered other user not in the group. Or am I completely wrong on this?

Comment: If you turn off "execute" permissions on a directory (not folder, unless you are using Windows, which works differently) you **DO NOT** have permission to view the contents.

Comment: So let me ask another question. All documentation I've read states "other"  as everyone else who is not in the group or the owner of file. When I enter user name and password of my user on the RPi into my PC FTP, is that considered the owner or other? I guess this is the part I'm lost at.